# What is the content of global .gitIgnore file?

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

Every time when I try to create new repository, I need to update my .gitignore file with some more comments. Now I am working with cocoapods so that my .gitigore file should ignore the userInterfaceState file changes. What is the comment I have to add to ignore the frequent commit. And is there any global .gitignore content which cover all the scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the github gitignore's:

https://github.com/github/gitignore

There are lot of templates for development frameworks or environments.

Answer (score 1):

To set a global gitignore file you can do this

```
git config --global core.excludesfile /home/user/.globalgitignore
```